# Determine which slack user has granted the access token

Tags: slack-api, slack

According to the [docs](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth), after a permission is granted, I receive this kind of JSON response:

```
{
    "access_token": "xoxp-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXX",
    "scope": "incoming-webhook,commands,bot",
    "team_name": "Team Installing Your Hook",
    "team_id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "incoming_webhook": {
        "url": "https://hooks.slack.com/TXXXXX/BXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX",
        "channel": "#channel-it-will-post-to",
        "configuration_url": "https://teamname.slack.com/services/BXXXXX"
    },
    "bot":{
        "bot_user_id":"UTTTTTTTTTTR",
        "bot_access_token":"xoxb-XXXXXXXXXXXX-TTTTTTTTTTTTTT"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to determine which slack user has granted the access?

Answer (score 1):

In case if anyone interested, slack team recently added `user_id` to the output. Moreover you can call web api method [auth.test](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test) which will give you the `user_id` if access token has been provided.